# Finding the location of my spark job output file

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am testing pyspark jobs in an EMR cluster on AWS. The goal is to use a Lambda function to fire the spark job, but for now I am manually running the spark job. So, I SSH to the master node and then run the spark job as below:

```
spark-submit /home/hadoop/testspark.py mybucket
```

mybucket - parameter passed to the spark job.

The line that saves the RDD is

```
rddFiltered.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/home/hadoop/output.txt")
```

The spark job seems to run but it puts the output file in some location - Output directory hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:8020/home/hadoop/output.txt.

1. Where is this exactly located and how can I view the contents? Forgive my ignorance on HDFS and Hadoop.
2. Eventually, I want to rename output.txt to something meaningful and then transfer to S3, just haven't gotten there yet.
3. If I re-run the spark job it says  "Output directory hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal:8020/home/hadoop/output.txt already exists". How do I prevent this or at least overwrite the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the EMR documentation: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html

if you do not specify prefix, spark will write data to HDFS by default. You can check EMR HDFS with this command:

```
hadoop fs -ls /home/hadoop/
```

You can also transfer from HDFS to S3 with S3DistCp:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html

Unfortunately you cannot overwrite the existing file using saveAsTextFile:

https://spark-project.atlassian.net/browse/SPARK-1100

As I can see you re-partitioned the file into one partition, so you can write it into the local file-system as well:

```
rddFiltered.repartition(1).collect().saveAsTextFile("file:///home/hadoop/output.txt")
```

Note, if you are using distributed cluster you have to `collect()` back to driver first!